# Call function every x seconds (Python)

Tags: python, api, loops, time

I want to call a function (actually, it is a web API) every 10 seconds. But the function may take random t second to return. (Assume t is 0.1 to 1.0 sec)

The simplest code we can think of is

```
while True:
    func()          # take t sec
    time.sleep(10)  # sleep 10 sec
```

but in this case, `func` is called every (1+t) seconds.
Are there better ways to do it?

Should we use some multi threading or something like that? Concrete code example will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239035/asynchronous-method-call-in-python maybe related? you could spawn a subproces for an async call every 10 seconds. It would not mater then how long the processing took.

Comment: Why don't you use `cron`?

Comment: You can use `sched`(scheduler) module which is present in python built-in standard library.

Comment: @YamanJain Can you show how to sched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remember when the next iteration is supposed to happen, roughly like this (not fully working code, I'm sure you can figure it out from here):

```
import time
nexttime = time.time()
while True:
    func()          # take t sec
    nexttime += 10
    sleeptime = nexttime - time.time()
    if sleeptime > 0:
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the simplest and the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

pool = Pool(processes=1)              # Start a worker processes.
while true:
    result = pool.apply_async(func, [10], callback=finish) # Evaluate "func(10)" asynchronously calling callback when finished.
    time.sleep(10)
```

This will call your function exactly every 10 seconds. As long as you are sure it will not take more than 10 seconds to return you should be ok with only one worker process. Sourced from here: [Asynchronous method call in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239035/asynchronous-method-call-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for the nice code. This is what I vaguely imagined of. I found that the interval is slightly longer than 10 sec, due to `pool.apply_async` invoking time.

Answer (score 1):

I found another approach using `sched` module.

```
import time
import sched

def daemon(local_handler, t):
    print('time {}'.format(t))
    # call func here
    # time.sleep(2)
    local_handler.enterabs(t + 10, 1, daemon, (local_handler, t+10))

handler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
t = time.time()
handler.enter(0, 1, daemon, (handler, t))
handler.run()
```

A good point of this approach is that we can control the time of the function exactly. For example we can call the function when the clock is 0.31, 10.31, 20.31, 30.31, ...

This code is taken from [Python Scheduler vs loop + sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216406/python-scheduler-vs-loop-sleep).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import time
start=time.perf_counter()
call_new_func()
while ((time.perf_counter()-start)<desired_time_wait):
    pass #busy-wait
```

Inside your `while True` loop.

Comment: Sure, if you want to waste electricity and slow down your computer!  Note OP's code has a duty cycle of less than 10%, so this will waste more than 90% of resources.

Comment: According to my understanding of https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/timemodule.c, this kind of loop (in C) is actually what Python does internally for `time.sleep()`.

Comment: No, Python uses `select()` or other non-busy-waiting approaches.  As you can see in the code for `pysleep` you linked.